# How to authenticate multiple Azure Apps against oauth2_proxy in Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, oauth2-proxy

I have two independent apps:

- First app is deployed in Kubernetes cluster behind [oauth2_proxy](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/).
- The second app is deployed in Azure App Service.

Both apps authenticate user against Azure Active Directory using oauth2 flow.

I'd like to use the Access Token of second app and use it to access the API of first app.

How can I do it so [oauth2_proxy](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/configuration/overview) validates it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add app's audience of second application to `--extra-jwt-issuers` argument. Here is the configuration and nitty-gritty details of how to use it.

```yaml
- --azure-tenant=11111111-2222-3333-4444-55555555
- --email-domain=*
- --http-address=0.0.0.0:4180
- --provider=oidc
- --set-authorization-header=true
- --set-xauthrequest=true
- --pass-access-token=true
- --pass-authorization-header=true
- --pass-user-headers=true
- --pass-host-header=true
- --skip-jwt-bearer-tokens=true
- --oidc-email-claim=oid
- --oidc-issuer-url=https://sts.windows.net/11111111-2222-3333-4444-55555555/
- --extra-jwt-issuers=https://sts.windows.net/11111111-2222-3333-4444-55555555/=api://app1-2222-3333-4444-55555555,https://sts.windows.net/11111111-2222-3333-4444-55555555/=api://app2-2222-3333-4444-55555555
```

As you can see above I'm actually adding two issuers, this is because I'm using two apps that need to be authenticated.